# nether portals and villagers minecraft bedrock addition problems

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm using the Nintendo Switch Bedrock Edition, and I wanted to build a village so I used nether portals to teleport villagers. For some reason, they are not able to  teleport using nether portals. I tried to put them in a boat so I could transport them, if that helps solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Entities that are riding other entities (ex. villagers in boats) can't travel to the nether. You have to remove the villagers from the boats and then get them into the nether portal some other way in order for the villagers to change dimensions.